# How can we pass the context dictionary in redirect function in django

Tags: python, django

I want to pass that 'liked' variable as a context dictionary through the redirect function. Please help me to do so.

```
def likepost(request, post_id):
    user = request.user
    post_connected = post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    mypost = like_post.objects.filter(user=user, liked=post_connected)

    if mypost.exists():
        mypost.delete()
        liked = False

    else:
        mylike = like_post.objects.create(user=user, liked=post_connected)
        mylike.save()
        liked = True

    return redirect('/')
```

This is my urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('search/', views.search, name='search'),
    path('follow/', views.follow, name='follow'),
    path('unfollow/', views.unfollow, name='unfollow'),
    path('create/', views.create, name='create'),
    path('follows/<str:userfollow>/', views.followers, name='followers'),
    path('like/<int:post_id>/', views.likepost, name='like')
]
```

Comment: You don't. A `redirect` is a HTTP response that basically asks the browser to visit another URL. So unless it is encoded in a URL parameter, or cookie, or something else, the new request is totally unaware of what happended at the server side.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So is there another way to do so??

Comment: no, or at least not without introducing global state. The entire idea is that the HTTP *protocol* should be *stateless*. Especially since if you later scale your application in a distributed manner, the next request might be processed by another server.

Comment: @VishalSingh I already tried that but it is then showing a NoReverseMatch error

Comment: @VishalSingh done

Comment: @VishalSingh i wanted to redirect to 'home'

Comment: did you try this `return redirect('home', context)`.

Comment: @VishalSingh Yes, i tried. Then also it is showing a NoReverseMatch error